# Font in TextView in horizontal LinearLayout does not match parent height?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

I understand that it has been discussed many times, but I can not find a solution.
I specially marked all in the colors. This is the AlertDialog.

[image]

Why trimmed the text itself? What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dialogs_background_gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialNewGroupCustomNameLay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/group_custom_name_label"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/newGrNameEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialNewGroupDefinedLangsLay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/newGrDialLangFrom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/newGrNameLay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/purple"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/groupNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/group_name_label"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newGrNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@string/group_name_label"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="17dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Added full XML. Also it is necessary to consider that LinearLayout is in AlertDialog.

Comment: Just remove `android:paddingBottom="30dp"` from your TextViews. Moreover, you really don't need **2** nested LinearLayout (bad for performances). A **single** RelativeLayout is more performant.

Comment: I checked your layout. It's showing correct on my system. can you post full xml?

Answer (score 0):

Text height + padding will result in height of Teaxtbox(match_parent).

Answer (score 0):

Your LinearLayout gets its height from its children:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and the children get height from the parent LinearLayout:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

It's the error. You should have a place where height is actually specified.

Comment: I understand, how to fix in my case?

Comment: Try setting `android:layout_height="100dp"` in newGrNameLay LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all paddings and margins bottoms and top. Added bottom a small view.

[image]

```
    <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"/>
```

It looks better.